# Perl replace regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

In `file.txt` I have a line like this:

`^/string  string_to_be_replaced`

that must become:

`^/string  replaced_string`

So I created a perl script:

```
perl -pi -e "s[\^/string$(.*)$] [\^/string$(.*) replaced_string]" /file.txt
```

But the problem is that perl doesn't find the line starting with `^/string`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e "s[\^/string .+$][^/string replaced_string]" /file.txt
```

or

```
perl -pi -e "s[\^/string \K.+$][replaced_string]" /file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The first portion of your regex, `[\^/string$(.)$]`, looks for a line containing "^/string", followed by an end-of-line, followed by a single character (which is captured), and finally another end-of-line.  Since the file is processed line-by-line (looking at only one line at a time), a pattern containing two end-of-lines can *never* match.

You probably want:

```
s[\^/string string_to_be_replaced][^/string replaced_string]
```

assuming that you have only a single `string_to_be_replaced` and only want to replace it when it's preceded by `string`.  If not, then more details would be useful.