# Perl literal regex

Tags: regex, perl

I need to search and substitute a regex. In fact the line:

`^/httpd/$ (some chars here)`

must be replaced with

`^/httpd$ (value of a variable named VAR)`

Therefore I used this:

```
perl -pi -e "s[^\Q^/httpd$\E(.*)$][\Q^/httpd$\E ${VAR}]" /file.conf
```

But nothing happens..

Comment: Use warnings. `-w`. You should always use warnings, because they give you crucial information.

Comment: If you are using linux (or similar) you might need to use single quotes for your Perl code to avoid shell interpolation.

Comment: @TLP: you mean single quotes in place of the double quotes I used?

Comment: Why would you ask that instead of just trying if that helps? I suppose TLP indeed meant that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The implied question you *should* have answered was which OS you used. But I am guessing that the implied answer here is that you are using linux (or similar).

Comment: Since you have not replied with the requested information, I cannot help you with an answer to your question. You can however try what I have already suggested, changing to single quotes, and then using `$ENV{VAR}` to access the shell's variable `$VAR`

Comment: Did you mean to remove the trailing slash after httpd? I.e. did you want `^/httpd/$` or `^/httpd$`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl replace regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517064/perl-replace-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have some confusion as to whether you have or want to have a trailing slash in your string, e.g. `httpd/$` or `httpd$`. If you do have it and did not put it in the regex, that is why it does not match.

But besides that, it is not a good idea to try and interpolate shell variables in a regex in Perl code. You use the `%ENV` hash for that, where the `$VAR` environment variable is denoted `$ENV{VAR}`.

As for the `\Q ... \E` and the `$`, it seems to be quite the dilemma. Because variables can be interpolated, you cannot use `$\E` because it will be interpreted as `$\` and the literal letter `E`. And you cannot escape the dollar sign because the `\Q ... \E` will escape the backslash. You can however, put the dollar sign outside the escape and escape it manually, e.g. `\E\$`.

You can also use the `\K` escape to "keep" parts of your string you do not want to remove.

Because you have not provided enough information, it is impossible to provide an exact answer, but I can guess. Here is my guess as to what you might need:

```
perl -pi -e 's[^\Q^/httpd/\E\$\K.*][ $ENV{VAR}]' /file.conf
```

Or perhaps more simply

```
perl -pi -e 's[^\^/httpd/\$\K.*][ $ENV{VAR}]' /file.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax instead:

```
 perl -pi -e "s/\^\/httpd\/\\$.*/^\/httpd\\$ ${VAR}/" /file.conf
```

In the initial regex, a `/` is missing. The shell interprets the `$` sign so perl doesn't "see" it in the regex.

#### Demo

**file.conf**

```
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqsdf
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqsdsdfgsdfgf
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqszezezedf
```

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=FOOBAR

echo BEFORE
more file.conf

perl -pi -e "s/\^\/httpd\/\\$.{0,}/^\/httpd\\$ ${VAR}/" file.conf

echo
echo
echo AFTER
more file.conf

echo
echo
echo 'done'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$bash -f main.sh 
BEFORE
::::::::::::::
file.conf
::::::::::::::
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqsdf
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqsdsdfgsdfgf
^/httpd/$ qsdfqsdfqsdfqszezezedf

AFTER
::::::::::::::
file.conf
::::::::::::::
^/httpd$ FOOBAR
^/httpd$ FOOBAR
^/httpd$ FOOBAR

done
```

Comment: What good is changing the delimiters back to `/` and adding the `/m` modifier?

Comment: @TLP I wasn't able to find a doc mentionning square brackets as delimiters, so I replaced them. Later, I had strange results: the shell interfers with command between double quotes passed to `perl`. `/m` modifier doesn't import here, so I removed it.

Comment: You can indeed change delimiters, and use just about any punctuation character. The double quotes will allow shell interpolation, which is why it is better to replace them with single quotes. Also, `{0,}` and `*` are identical quantifiers.

Comment: @TLP shell interpolation is needed by OP because she uses `${VAR}`. This shell interpolation was particularly challenging in order to solve this question. I have updated my answser with `*`.

Comment: It is not needed, because the `%ENV` hash contains that variable.